# Array and pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int *ptr = array;
std::cout<<*(ptr+ 2); => O/P = 3

int (*arr_ptr)[10] = &array;
std::cout<<*(*arr_ptr+2); => O/P = 3
```

Whats the difference between these 2. I know what they mean, but if they give same result why do we have 2 different notations?

Comment: We have different notations because there are different ways to express the concept. Just like natural language has synonyms.

Comment: But here ptr points to array[0], but *arr_ptr points to array[0]...So its better t use ptr notation right?

Comment: I have put the type of `arr_ptr` and edited your question. See if it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

The first case is the normal case: `ptr` is a pointer to the first element of the array `array`, and it is indexed (using `*(ptr+2)`, which is a synonym for `ptr[2]`) to access the third element of that array.

The second case is contrived: `arr_ptr` is a pointer to the (enitre) array `array`. It is first dereferenced (with `*arr_ptr`) to yield the array itself, which is then used as an argument to binary `+`, which causes it to get implicitly converted to a (nameless) pointer to its first element, which is then indexed in the same way `*(<nameless pointer>+2)` and gives the same result.

Making those implicit conversions explicit, you could write

```
int *ptr = &array[0];
std::cout<<*(ptr+ 2);

int (*arr_ptr)[10] = &array;
std::cout<<*( &(*arr_ptr)[0] + 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

After editing your question, following are the differences:

```
(1) int *ptr = array;
```

`array` gets decayed to the pointer. `ptr` is ideally allowed to point to any `int[]` irrespective of its size

```
(2) int (*arr_ptr)[10] = &array;
```

`arr_ptr` is a pointer to an `int[10]`. It's very specific definition and you can never assign an array to `arr_ptr` which has size other than `10`.

```
int array_2[20];
arr_ptr = &array_2; // error
```

Comment: Yes got it...But the & operator is not necessary I suppose.

Comment: @Mayuresh, it's **necessary in the case of pointer to array**. Otherwise it will give [compiler error](http://www.ideone.com/WHNpG).

Comment: I tried it without & operator on Visual Studio 2010...It does not give any errors....

Answer (score 0):

Use the notation that you understand and that fits the problem domain. If your app has an array, then use array notation. If you have to push pointers around for some other reason, then the second version is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

They are not in fact the same to the compiler, and will result in different assembly language being generated.

Here is some good reference on the difference: http://cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10/

Comment: No problem.. although I am now second guessing myself since in the second part your example, I'm not sure what happens when you declare/initialize the array of pointers.  I suspect it may statically allocate the space for 10 pointers, but I'm not certain.